# How to add a specific line in a file to the end of the specific line in another file？ （use sed maybe)

Tags: linux, sed, tcsh

I have a file, `supermaster.PRM`:

```
num_valid_az    = 12194 
nrows           = 12194 
first_line          = 1 
deskew          = n 
caltone         = 0.000000 
st_rng_bin          = 1 
Flip_iq         = n 
offset_video    = n 
az_res          = 0.000000 
nlooks          = 1 
chirp_ext           = 0 
scnd_rng_mig    = 0 
rng_spec_wgt    = 1.000000 
rm_rng_band         = 0.200000 
rm_az_band          = 0.000000 
rshift          = -18 
ashift          = 0 
stretch_r           = 0 
stretch_a           = 0 
a_stretch_r     = 0 
a_stretch_a     = 0 
first_sample    = 284 
SC_identity         = 10 
rng_samp_rate       = 64345238.125714 
input_file      = S1_20160114_ALL_F1.raw 
num_rng_bins        = 67752 
bytes_per_line      = 271008 
good_bytes_per_line = 271008 
PRF         = 486.486310 
pulse_dur       = 5.240481e-05 
near_range      = 799926.599409 
num_lines       = 12194 
num_patches     = 1 
SC_clock_start      = 2016013.0823712260 
SC_clock_stop       = 2016013.0826613354 
clock_start     =  13.082371226227 
clock_stop          =  13.082661335643 
led_file        = S1_20160114_ALL_F1.LED 
orbdir  = A 
lookdir = R 
radar_wavelength    = 0.0554658 
chirp_slope = 1.07815e+12 
rng_samp_rate       = 64345238.125714 
I_mean          = 0 
Q_mean          = 0 
SC_vel          = 7160.742699 
earth_radius        = 6371038.614500 
equatorial_radius   = 6378137.000000 
polar_radius        = 6356752.310000 
SC_height       = 699860.307600 
SC_height_start = 699988.203956 
SC_height_end   = 699732.953774 
fd1         = 0.000000 
fdd1            = 0.000000 
fddd1           = 0.000000 
sub_int_r               = 0.000000 
sub_int_a               = 0.000000 
SLC_file               = S1_20160114_ALL_F1.SLC 
dtype           = a 
SLC_scale               = 1.000000
```

In this supermaster.PRM file, I want to take the ' rng_samp_rate = 64345238.125714 ' -- I know there are two, but I only need one --
to put it into this shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=InSAR
#SBATCH --ntasks=128
#SBATCH --time=7-00:00:00
#SBATCH --mail-type=fail,end
#SBATCH --export=all
#SBATCH --out=Forge-%j.out
#SBATCH --mem=256000

module load GMT
module load GMTSAR
module load parallel
sbas intf.tab scene.tab 19 10 8469 6097 
csh plot_sbas.csh
```

to the end of sbas line like

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=InSAR
#SBATCH --ntasks=128
#SBATCH --time=7-00:00:00
#SBATCH --mail-type=fail,end
#SBATCH --export=all
#SBATCH --out=Forge-%j.out
#SBATCH --mem=256000

module load GMT
module load GMTSAR
module load parallel
sbas intf.tab scene.tab 19 10 8469 6097 -rng_samp_rate = 64345238.125714
csh plot_sbas.csh
```

Comment: Please explain **in your question** how/why you select `1122.1223` from `file1.txt`. Because it has the same line number as `sbas`? Because it is always line 2, independent from the line that contains `sbas` in `main.txt`? Because it follows `222`? ...

Comment: @Bodo I add my real condition to the question

Comment: I suggest to remove the part with `file1.txt` and `main.txt` because these files differ tto much from your real requirements. If there are two occurrences of `rng_samp_rate` is it OK to always use the first one? Please clarify this in your question.

Comment: @Bodo Yes I always use the first 'rng_samp_rate', I will edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `awk` script:

```
awk 'NR==FNR && /^rng_samp_rate/ { value=$0 } 
     NR!=FNR && !/^sbas/         { print }
     NR!=FNR && /^sbas/          { print $0 " -" value }' supermaster.PRM script.in > script.out
```

The first file must be the parameters file, the second file the shell script to be modified. (This `awk` script takes the last occurrence of `rng_samp_rate`.)

The output is

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=InSAR
#SBATCH --ntasks=128
#SBATCH --time=7-00:00:00
#SBATCH --mail-type=fail,end
#SBATCH --export=all
#SBATCH --out=Forge-%j.out
#SBATCH --mem=256000

module load GMT
module load GMTSAR
module load parallel
sbas intf.tab scene.tab 19 10 8469 6097  -rng_samp_rate       = 64345238.125714 
csh plot_sbas.csh
```

Of course you can also use other tools like `grep` and `sed`.

```
sed "s/^sbas.*/& -$(grep '^rng_samp_rate' supermaster.PRM|head -1)/" script.in > script.out
```

or maybe a bit easier to understand

```
#! /bin/sh
VALUE="$(grep '^rng_samp_rate' supermaster.PRM|head -1)"
sed "s/^sbas.*/& -$VALUE/" script.in > script.out
```

(Here I use the first occurrence of `rng_samp_rate`.)

Both commands assume that no other lines start with `rng_samp_rate` or `sbas` and that the parameter file always contains a `rng_samp_rate` line.
The `sed` script assumes that the value line from the parameter file does not contain a `/`.

---

Edit: How to modify the script file instead of creating a new output file?

Some commands, e.g. `sed`, support in-place editing which you can use to modify the script file without explicitly creating a separate output file.

```
sed  -i .bak -e "some script" script.in
```

In general you can always follow the command with a suitable `mv` command, e.g.

```
awk 'some script' supermaster.PRM script.in > script.out && mv script.out script.in
```

The `&&` makes sure your original script gets overwritten only if the `awk` command did not indicate an error.

If you want to do more modifications you can extend the `awk` or `sed` script (best performance) or run several scripts sequentially or connected to a pipe. (For details you should write the additional requirements.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! all of the solutions works! I'm not familiar with awk so I want to ask if I want 'awk' changing the source file script.in rather than generate the script.out what should I do? because I need to keep adding parameters behind the sbas line

Comment: @Jerry `awk` doesn't support in-place  editing like `sed` or `perl`. I added a work-around to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could script this with `ed`:

```sh
printf '%s\n' \
  '/^sbas /s/$/ -/' \
  '. r !grep ^rng_samp_rate supermaster.PRM | head -1' \
  '-1,.j' \
  'w' \
  'q' | ed -s shellscript
```

This changes the (first) line that stars with the text "`sbas`" to append a space and a dash. It then reads output from a shell command to the subsequent line; the shell command searches for the text "`rng_samp_rate`" at the beginning of the line in supermaster.PRM, then uses `head -1` to grab only the first such result.  That output is then joined with the previous line. Then we save the file to disk and exit.

If the additional spaces from the original text are a problem, you could squeeze them by modifying the shell code slightly:

```
...
grep ^rng_samp_rate supermaster.PRM | head -1 | sed 's/  */ /'
...
```

... which just adds a `sed` command that replaces 1 or more spaces with a single space. If extra spaces can occur after the equals-sign, change the sed command to: `sed 's/  */ /g'`.